# assigning dynamic executed queries to variable

Tags: sql

I am using `sp_executesql` to run one dynamic query to in my sproc and assigning to variable. However when I execute I am not getting any result. can someone help me whats wrong with my query.

```
@L_TNAME & @P_ID will get the values during run time.

DECLARE @sSQL VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

 SET @sSQL= N'SELECT @L_TYPE_NAMEOUT= type FROM '+ @L_TNAME +'  WHERE id ='+ @P_ID;
 SET @ParmDefinition = N'@L_TYPE_NAMEOUT VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT';

 EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, @ParmDefinition, @L_TYPE_NAMEOUT=@L_TYPE_NAME OUTPUT;
 SELECT @L_TYPE_NAME;
```

Comment: This is not ANSI SQL, please tag product properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is @P_ID having a datatype of int/bigint. In such a scenario cast the same and you will get the output

```
SET @sSQL= N'SELECT @L_TYPE_NAMEOUT= type FROM '+ @L_TNAME +'  WHERE id ='+ CAST(@P_ID AS VARCHAR);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes @P_id is int type and I have cast that to varchar. still I am not getting the output out of it.

Comment: I found out the issue. I have declared @sSQL as varchar instead of Nvarchar. I have changed it and its working.